# Dolphin add media columns

Tags: dolphin

Is there any way to add media-columns like **Length** or **Date Created** to Dolphin.

I'm using Dolphin Version 15.12.3 and ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Yes..In details view, right click the top bar of the display pane and choose from the drop-down list of attributes.

Comment: length is not there